# Contact Same No On Account Trigger Test class

Tags: trigger, unit-test, error-messages

How do I cover `addError()` in `Unit Test Class` for the below Trigger.

```
trigger ContactSameNoOnAccountTrigger on Contact (before insert) {
    List<Account> objAccount = new List<account>();

    for(Contact objContact:Trigger.new) {
          objAccount = [SELECT id,Name,Phone FROM Account WHERE phone=:objContact.phone];
          if(objAccount.size()>0){
            objContact.addError('phone no aleredy exists in account'); 
          }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: create one account with same phonenumber. BTW you are making SOQL in for loop its a bad practice and you will hit the limit easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for test class. But you need to rework on your trigger logic as `SOQL` inside the `for loop` is not good coding practice

```
@isTest
private class TriggerTest {

    static testMethod void unitTest() {
      Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Trigger', phone = '12345678');
      insert acc;
      Contact Con = new Contact(LastName = 'TestTrigger', AccountId = acc.id, phone = '12345678');
      insert Con;
      //assert statement
    }
}
```